# MySQL: Replace rows in one table with rows from another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is kind if driving me nuts but that's what code does, right?

I have two identically structured tables but the data isn't identical.  One table is "today" while the other is "yesterday".  Each day, I'd like to take the rows in today to be moved to yesterday.  They also have the same primary key "coords".  I don't want to move all the data at once, only at the coords I provide.  Here's some of what I've tried so far with no luck:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("REPLACE INTO yesterday SELECT * FROM today WHERE coords=?");

$stmt = $con->prepare("REPLACE yesterday
            INNER JOIN today USING (coords)
            WHERE coords=?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, it was a data type problem.  My coords data looks like this "+59.5,-88.1" and it must have freaked out about it.  Thanks to those who took a peek.